# Elasticsearch parent-child searching

Tags: elasticsearch

My mappings:

```
"mappings": {
"role_permission_parent": {
  "properties": {
    "resourceURI": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "resourceLabel": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
},
"role_permission_child": {
  "_parent": {
    "type": "role_permission_parent"
  },
  "properties": {
    "resourceURI": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "resourceLabel": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
}
```

I have over 100k document indexed by parents.

`Question:`
*How can I permoform searching accross childs inside some parent?* 
That mean.. I want to find child with value "someting" in field "resourceLabale" inside "_parent":12345.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for the parent with the id 12345 and have a `has_child` query that search for `value: something`

looks like this

```
bool:
  must:
    term: parentId: 12345
    has_child:
      term:
        something: value
```

See the [has_child query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-has-child-query.html)